# Create an email, allow the user to send, then execute further code

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro that collects information from existing emails and a local database, then serves up a templated email with the information. The user can review the email, make changes if they want to and then send or not sent (quit/cancel).

Is there a way, I can keep the macro running and then execute more code if the user sends the email?

Psuedo code of how it might work:

```
Function CreateEmailThenExecuteCode()
    Dim newEmail As MailItem
    Set newEmail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    newEmail.Display
    'Allow user to review and send email
    'If they 'send', then execute further code.
    
    If Not Sent Then Exit Function
    
    'Further code
End Function
```

I know I can create a macro that runs every time a user sends an email, but it would be much easier if I can keep the existing macro running, as otherwise I need a way of saving the data from the running macro.

I also know I can create a custom user form that mimics an email user form, but I prefer to keep the functionality of the full email user form, especially with access to email address lists etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Display` method doesn't prevent your code from running until you pass `true` to make the Inspector window modal. The default value is `false`.

At the same keeping the code running after the `Display` call doesn't allow users to deal with Outlook UI because the VBA code will be run on the main thread (UI).

You may consider setting up an event handler for the [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.send(even)) event which is fired when the user selects the `Send` action for an item, or when the `Send` method is called for the item. So, you will be aware when the item is sent out.

Also you may find the [MailItem.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.close(even)) event helpful. It is fired when the inspector associated with an item is being closed. So, you will also be aware when the item is closed.

Comment: For my purposes, having no access to the rest of the Outlook UI is fine - so passing true as the modal parameter works a treat. In fact, I want the user to be forced to deal with this email before doing anything else (it's part of a workflow process). I can then check mailitem.sent to see whether the user actually sent the email.

Perfect!